# Can Raw Input Registration be done from one application for another application?

Tags: c++, windows, raw-input

I've tried two things, one is as mentioned in the title.

Case 1: In one C++ console application (App_A) I register for RawInput but the window handle is that of another application (App_B) that has WM_INPUT configured to listen and work with the raw input data.

Case 2: The other is registering the raw input on the C++ console application (App_A) itself (creating a window for it of course) and using PostMessageA inside the WM_Input I've set up to send over or forward the lparam of the WM_INPUT on the console application (App_A) to the WM_INPUT of the other application (App_B).

In case 1 the registration made from App_A for another App_B's window does not seem to cause the APP_B to pick up WM_INPUT events.

In case 2 the forwarding with PostMessage from App_A to App_B does cause App_B's WM_INPUT to get hit but the data there seems not work.

I'm looking into if what I'm doing is sensible and if there are any native restrictions preventing me from this approach.

Doing this because I'm trying to understand better, I could just register for input directly on App B yes....

Comment: `WM_INPUT`'s arguments are valid for the duration of processing this message only. Posting it to a different thread's queue won't work.

Comment: I can confirm case 2 does work after printing out some logs, it was just that the breakpoint would hit when my mouse would be still (so it could click on it) so it would also show a size of 0 thinking the mouse hadn't moved which is technically true.

Comment: *Posting* the message via `PostMessage()` won't work, since the data is destroyed after the original `WM_INPUT` message is done being processed, before the posted message is processed. But *sending* the message via `SendMessage()` has a better chance of working. Except, is the received `HRAWINPUT` handle even valid across process boundaries? The documentation does not say one way or the other, so don't assume it is. The original `WM_INPUT` handler should extract the data as needed and send it to the other process via any IPC mechanism of your choosing, such as `WM_COPYDATA` for instance.